# Enable razor intellisense Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I've been struggling to get intellisense to work correctly in .cshtml files which use razor.  After reading blog posts, articles, and other stack overflow questions giving advice for VS2012, different versions of MVC, updates to webtools, and so on, I still have no intellisense in .cshtml files.

I decided to uninstall and remove all copies of Visual Studio 2012, 2013, MVC, Webtools, and delete any leftover folders.  Then I did a clean install of the latest release of Visual Studio Express 2013 for web and the first .cshtml document i opened had the correct highlighting and intellisense!  With much excitement I opened another .cshtml document... and the intellisense was not there!  I then went back to the first .cshtml document and too it was gone!  I closed VS2013, reopened, restarted, but no avail.

I'm quite perplexed.  I'm looking for any advice for enabling intellisense for .cshtml files in visual studio 2013 for web.

Comment: After much toil I got intellisense to work again by launching VWDexpress.exe /resetsettings from command line.

Comment: @Doug how did u get your intellisense working i am also facing the same problem